# Sort GitHub pull requests by target branch

Tags: github

I receive [many pull requests](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pulls), each targeting either of 3+ branches (develop, freeze, hotfix-*). Before I release, I would like to check whether any pull request remains for the branch I want to release.

The destination branch is not even visible on list items (visible is the origin branch) so I have to go inside each single pull request to see the destination branch, which is a pain:

[image: GitHub example]

How to achieve this?